# Prevent windows shutdown from python

Tags: python, windows, shutdown

I want to prevent windows (xp and 7) from shutting down.
For that it seems I have to intercept the WM_QUERYENDSESSION message and return False.

**Ok I have to correct my statement, this program works fine under Windows 7 but on Windows 7 embedded Standard Service Pack 1 it does not prevent the shutdown!?**

```
import ctypes
from ctypes import c_long, c_int, c_wchar_p
import time
import win32api
import win32con
import win32gui
import win32process

oldWndProc = None

def wndproc(hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam):
    print("wndproc received message: %s" % msg)
    if (msg == win32con.WM_QUERYENDSESSION):
        print("wndproc received WM_QUERYENDSESSION")
        return 0
    # Pass all messages to the original WndProc
    return win32gui.CallWindowProc(oldWndProc, hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    try:
        # Create a window just to be able to receive WM_QUERYENDSESSION messages
        win32api.SetLastError(0)
        hinst = win32api.GetModuleHandle(None)
        messageMap = {}
        wndclass = win32gui.WNDCLASS()
        wndclass.hInstance = hinst
        wndclass.lpszClassName = "PreventShutdownWindowClass"
        wndclass.lpfnWndProc = messageMap
        myWindowClass = win32gui.RegisterClass(wndclass)
        hwnd = win32gui.CreateWindowEx(win32con.WS_EX_LEFT,
                                     myWindowClass,
                                     "PreventShutdownWindow", 
                                     0, 
                                     0, 
                                     0, 
                                     win32con.CW_USEDEFAULT, 
                                     win32con.CW_USEDEFAULT, 
                                     0, 
                                     0, 
                                     hinst, 
                                     None)
        print 'CreateWindowEx: ' + str(hwnd)
        print 'CreateWindowEx last error: ' + str(win32api.GetLastError())
        print ''

        # Set WndProc
        win32api.SetLastError(0)
        WndProcType = ctypes.WINFUNCTYPE(c_int, c_long, c_int, c_int, c_int)
        newWndProc = WndProcType(wndproc)
        oldWndProc = ctypes.windll.user32.SetWindowLongW( hwnd, win32con.GWL_WNDPROC, newWndProc )
        print 'SetWindowLong: ' + str(oldWndProc)
        print 'SetWindowLong last error: ' + str(win32api.GetLastError())
        print ''

        # We provide a reason for the shutdown prevention
        win32api.SetLastError(0)
        ret = ctypes.windll.user32.ShutdownBlockReasonCreate(hwnd, c_wchar_p("PreventShutdown running which prevents shutdown"))
        print 'ShutdownBlockReasonCreate: ' + str(ret)
        print 'ShutdownBlockReasonCreatelast error: ' + str(win32api.GetLastError())
        print ''

        # We elevate the program to be asked as soon as possible to inhibit shutdown
        win32api.SetLastError(0)
        win32process.SetProcessShutdownParameters(0x4FF, win32con.SHUTDOWN_NORETRY)
        print 'SetProcessShutdownParameters last error: ' + str(win32api.GetLastError())
        print ''

    except Exception, e:
        print("Exception: %s" % str(e))

    while True:
        win32gui.PumpWaitingMessages()
        time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Can you post the code you're using to attempt to return ```False```?

Comment: It's the code from my link, I didn't want to duplicate it, which I can if appropriate. the code would be def wndproc(hwnd, msg, wparam, lparam): return False

Comment: you should duplicate only the relevant code here

Comment: I expect the edition of Windows that you are using differs in the way it operates. My guess is that it doesn't allow apps to veto shutdown. You are probably expected not to shutdown in the first place.

Comment: David: Yes it seems like this, but this difference is nowhere documented in the MSDN docu. So I would consider this a bug in Windows Embedded :-(